# Multi-objective optimization with both equality and inequality constraints in R

Tags: r, optimization

I have a multi-objective optimization problem with both equality and inequality constraints. I tried GA package in R but I didn't figure out how to set equality constraints like the GA in Matlab. Could anybody give some suggestions about which algorithm could I use in R and how to solve that. Thanks a lot. The problem is like below:
Objective functions(I would like to find a set of w1,w2,w3,w4,w5 to minimize f1, and at the same time I want to make f2 as small as possible):

```
f1<-(w1)^2+4*(w2)^4+3*(w3)^2+5*w4+w5
f2<-((w1)-(w2)^2+3(w3)^2-4*(w4)^3-w5)^2-8
```

Constraints:

```
w1+w2+w3+w4+w5=1
0<w1,w2,w3,w4,w5<1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use normalization so you can drop the equality constraint:

Objectives:

```
 w <- w / sum(w)
 f1<-(w1)^2+4*(w2)^4+3*(w3)^2+5*w4+w5
 f2<-((w1)-(w2)^2+3(w3)^2-4*(w4)^3-w5)^2-8
```

Constraints:

```
 0 <= w1,w2,w3,w4,w5 <= 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, if you have time, could you post the process of doing that?